# Keeping shared memory data in the case of reboot?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

I am currently using shmget and shmat to create a shared memory between two process. When the process die the shared memory is still alive and restarting the process mean we can start where we were before. But if the machine is turned off then turned on we are losing the data.

I would like to know if there was an option in shmget/shmat or another method to make shared memory between process in order to keep the data alive even in the case of a reboot.

Right now i am doing this kind of thing :

```
const char *ZoneFile = "/home/Zone.dat";'
key_t sharedKeyZone;
int sharedSpaceIdZone;

int descriptor = open(ZoneFile, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);
close(descriptor);
sharedKeyZone = ftok(ZoneFile, 1);
sharedSpaceIdZone = shmget(sharedKeyZone, 1 * sizeof(Zone_t), IPC_CREAT);
ZoneArray = (Zone_t *) shmat(sharedSpaceIdZone, NULL, 0);
```

Zone_t being a structure type, i can access every data in ZoneArray[0] from my 2 process without problem.

Right now the only solution i can think of would be to periodicaly write a ini file with the data to "save" the state of the system and when restart it read this file but this would be not flexible at all if the structure must evolve later.

EDIT : following the idea of @Wumpus Q. Wumbley i tried to use mmap with msync this way :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

//add rt to eclipse librairies

typedef struct count {

    int counter;
} count;

int main()
{
    count *memory;
    int fd = shm_open("MYmemory.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);

    if(fd == -1)
    {
        perror("shm_open");
        return 1;
    }

    ftruncate(fd, sizeof(count));
    memory = mmap(NULL, sizeof(count), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    printf("before %d\n", memory->counter);
    memory->counter = 5;
    printf("after %d\n", memory->counter);
    if(msync(memory, sizeof(count),MS_SYNC)<0)
    {
        printf("%s","msync ERROR.");
    }
    else { printf("%s","msync completed successfully.");}

    return 0;
}
```

Same result as with shmget and shmat, after a reboot the data are 0. (the printf "before" show 0)

EDIT 2 :

This did it for me :

```
    count *memory;
    int fd = open(MYmemoryFile, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);

    ftruncate(fd, sizeof(count));
    memory = mmap(NULL, sizeof(count), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    printf("before %d\n", memory->counter);
    memory->counter = 5;
    printf("after %d\n", memory->counter);
    if(msync(memory, sizeof(count),MS_SYNC)<0)
    {
        printf("%s","msync ERROR.");
    }
    else { printf("%s","msync completed successfully.\n");}
```

Still not perfect since everywhere in my former code i was using my memory without pointer form (Zone[0].param is now Zone[0]->param for example) but this is  a step forward, thanks to  @Wumpus Q. Wumbley.

EDIT 3 : If someone search about it later, here is how i fixed it to work with structure :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

//add rt to eclipse librairies


const char *MYmemoryFile = "/home/memorystruct.txt";


typedef struct count
{
    int counter;
    int test;
} match[5];

int main()
{

    int fd = open(MYmemoryFile, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);

    ftruncate(fd, sizeof(match));
    struct count *memory = mmap(NULL, sizeof(match), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    printf("before memory[0].counter %d\n", memory[0].counter);
    printf("before memory[0].counter %d\n", memory[0].test);
    printf("before memory[1].counter %d\n", memory[1].counter);
    memory[0].counter = 5;
    memory[0].test = 2;
    memory[1].counter = 17;
    printf("after memory[0].counter %d\n", memory[5].counter);
    printf("after memory[1].counter %d\n", memory[1].counter);
    if(msync(memory, sizeof(match),MS_SYNC)<0)
    {
        printf("%s","msync ERROR.");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s","msync completed successfully.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it is mission critical data then would you not rather use an external queue of some sort?

Comment: I am sorry if i don't understand the comment but wouldn't a queue regulate the order of the accebility to a memory rather than the persistence of it ?

Comment: As far as I know, `shm_open` creates the file in a temporary directory that will be gone after a reboot. So you need to choose a directory, create the file with a normal open, ftruncate it to the length you want, and then mmap it. None of the functions with names starting with "shm" are actually needed.

Comment: This is what i am currently doing (not hiding that i used /temp first...), now i am working in a /home directory where the files are still there. For example in my EDIT the file "MYmemory.txt" is not erased if i reboot the system but the data in it (memory->counter) is set back to 0 even if i set it to 5 before rebooting. I am feeling like this is really something small but the solution is avoiding me. EDIT:Well, after manually erasing the file it seems the program run but i can't find where the file exist now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you `mmap` a regular file with `MAP_SHARED`, you effectively have a shm segment that is also a permanent file. The copy on disk will lag behind the copy in memory, but you can call `msync` to flush it periodically.

Comment: Nice.  There might be issues with updates to the shared memory being only partially saved to disk, however.  Some sort of flush on a clean shutdown would probably be necessary.

Comment: I searched about this a little and tried to do a small code like this (see edit)